# need help debugging why css fails

Tags: css

i have markup like

shown [here](http://cssdesk.com/pUgrZ)

i am wondering why it seems like lines 12 & 13

```
.notes:link span,
.notes:visited span { ...
```

seems like its working

```
.comments span,
background-position: -16px -16px;
}
.permalink:link span,
.permalink:visited span {
background-position: -32px -16px;
}
```

seems like its non existent

for some reason, cssdesk seems to be down in that case code below ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .notes:link span,
    .notes:visited span, 
    .comments span,
    .permalink:link span,
    .permalink:visited span {
      background: url("http://static.tumblr.com/ikeq9mi/F6Tl4vrjj/metasprite.jpg") no-repeat;
      padding-right: 16px; /* width */
      font-size: 15px; /* height */
      margin: 0 2px;
      position: relative;
      top: -1px;
    }
    .notes:link span,
    .notes:visited span {
      background-position: 0 -16px;
    }
    .comments span,
      background-position: -16px -16px;
    }
    .permalink:link span, 
    .permalink:visited span {
      background-position: -32px -16px;
    }
    .notes:hover span,
    .notes:active span {
      background-position: 0 0;
    }
    .comments span,
      background-position: -16px 0;
    }
    .permalink:hover span,
    .permalink:active span {
      background-position: -32px 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="{Permalink}#notes" class="notes" title="notes">{NoteCount}<span></span></a> / 
<span class="comments">
  <a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread" class="dsq-comment-count" title="comments">Comments</a>
  <span></span>
</span> / 
<a href="{Permalink}" class="permalink" title="permalink"><span></span></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Better you post your HTML and CSS here. It makes it easier for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should have

```
.comments span {
    background-position: -16px -16px;
}
```

instead of

```
.comments span,
    background-position: -16px -16px;
}
```

Comment: +1 Quicker than I spotting this, here's the updated version: http://cssdesk.com/gCZu8

Answer (score 0):

Well, the CSS you've posted is incorrect, you are missing an opening brace, things like this will cause inconsistent parsing in browsers.

```
.comments span,
background-position: -16px -16px;
}
```

should be

```
.comments span {
background-position: -16px -16px;
}
```